# Do I have enough time to connect from Copenhagen airport to Aalborg in Denmark?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, short-connections, connecting-flights

I am an Australian citizen flying from Toronto, Canada to [Aalborg, Denmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aalborg_Airport).

There is one stop on this flight in [Copenhagen, Denmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_Airport).

The time between arrival in Copenhagen at 10:30 am and taking off to Aalborg at 12:00 pm is 1:30 hours.

Is this enough time to board the Aalborg flight? Will the passport check take longer than this?

Is there any way I can be prioritised due to the flight connection that I have?

Comment: Are both flights under one PNR (Passenger Name Record), or do you have two PNRs?

Comment: just one booking for the whole trip from A to Z

Comment: SAS has 4 later flights (on the random weekday I checked), with the last one being 9 hours later than your original flight. So don't worry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because both flights' tickets were issued under one PNR, the ticketing (and operating) air carriers are confident that the connection can be made.

If a one-PNR two-flight itinerary fails because the traveler is too late for the second flight, the airline is responsible to get the traveler to the destination, to care for the traveler on the way (food and lodging, if the delay is overnight), and may be liable for monetary damages as well. This is enough pain for airlines to be very careful to sell only ticket pairs with connections the airlines are confident can be made.

No one knows for sure what'll happen on your trip, but the smart money says you'll be fine.

Comment: Should be added that CPH is quite compact as well. Shortest I've had there is 20 minutes (admittedly both Schengen flights), and that was no problem for me. It was a slight problem for my luggage.